# How to replace Background-attachment:fixed on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-attachment

I have various sections on my website that offer a "**parallax**" style effect on backgrounds, this is disabled on many mobile platforms.

I wanted to use some jQuery or javascript to replace all instances of the style `"background-attachment:fixed"` for `"background-attachment: scroll"`.

I am not keen to update every location manually (Its a huge project) and I am happy to lose the Parallax effect on mobile and fall back to `background-size: cover`

Not posted any code as I am unsure where to start with this.

Comment: Would you be open to using css media queries to disable the effect based on screen size?

Comment: I would but to do this I would need to create a media query for each possible variation - there are over 100 across the whole project. I saw JS as being a one line way to disable the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all of these elements share same class name, say `bg`, then it could be something like this:

**JS: [JS Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/mh2ahtrw/3/)** - *I forgot about the for-loop here in pure javascript*

```
if(isMobile) {
    var backgrounds = document.getElementsByClassName('bg');

    for(var i in backgrounds){
        backgrounds[i].style.backgroundAttachment = 'scroll';
    }
}
```

**jQuery: [JS Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/mh2ahtrw/)**

```
if(isMobile) {
    $('.bg').css({'background-attachment':'scroll'});
}
```

- *Note that `isMobile` is presumably a variable you trigger `true` if it is mobile depending on `userAgent` or window width*

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
if (!window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)").matches) {  
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item.style.backgroundAttachment == "fixed") {
          item.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll";
      }
    }
}
```

I have not tested this, and I suspect it won't work for your problem because you don't have one class name. You could also run it on all `div`s or something.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet below

```js
//find all elements
var elements=document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
//loop through all elements
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;++i){
  //find the inline or css style for each element
element_style=window.getComputedStyle(elements[i],null)||elements[i].currentStyle;
//if style matches fixed change style
  if(element_style.backgroundAttachment=='fixed'){
console.log(element_style.backgroundAttachment)
elements[i].style.backgroundAttachment='scroll';
    //alert box that show style has been changed
alert('this div background is now '+ element_style.backgroundAttachment)
}

}
```

```css
div{
  background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQARVdhCSrk0o1t6uon-TqIJYit7b6unGWMn_zJu2Tg0LkoEi4Kpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:50px;
  border:solid;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;

}
```

```html
<div>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
</div>

<div>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
</div>
<div>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
Something here <br>
</div>
```